# Change text on event React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to change some text when an event happens. But I don't know how to do it.

I saw some tutorials where people are creating a new component. But is this the way? Because it is one sentence of text that needs to be replaced.

This is my code, I have some text that is displayed. And underneath I am displaying an agenda. When I press an day (onDayPress) I want to replace the text inside the text key with the text printed in my console.log.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (

      <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={styles.headline}>Januari 2018</Text>

          <Agenda
              onDayPress={(day)=>{
                  console.log(LocaleConfig.locales['nl'].monthNames[day.month - 1] + " " + day.year)
              />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Can someone help me or point me in the right direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **state** to store the text. Initialize your state with the default value, then when user click on Agenda, change that text and render the same.
Hope following code will help.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
 constructor(args) {
   super(args);
   this.state = {
     text: 'Januari 2018'
   };
 }

 render() {
  const { text } = this.state;
  return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.headline}>{text}</Text>
      <Agenda
          onDayPress={(day)=>{
              this.setState({
               text: LocaleConfig.locales['nl'].monthNames[day.month - 1] + " " + day.year
          });
      />
  </View>
  );
 }
}
```